# grub rescue toughies

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, grubrescue, mbr

I booted a custom distro from a Live CD. I decided to dual boot with WinXP, so I created a small partition and installed the OS. There was a little incompatibility with the processors that I fixed, but in the middle of using the OS, the desktop stalled so I hard reset the desktop by holding the power button for 3 seconds. I power back up, and I'm sent to grub rescue.

I'm familiar with grub rescue's extremely limited command line. I check the "set" and the root and prefix is correct. So I try to load the `normal.mod` so that I could use the regular grub command line and boot manually from there. However I encountered a singular problem:

```
Error: reloc offset is out of segment

grub rescue> set

Prefix = (hd0,5)/boot/grub

Root = hd0,5

grub rescue> insmod (hd0,5)/boot/grub/normal.mod

error: reloc offset is out of segment
```

My question: What does `reloc offset is out of segment` mean, and how do I fix it. I really DO NOT want to make another live CD or use a Windows Recovery Disc to restore the MBR.

Comment: Could you say if you used a vanilla version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is caused by an error in some of the drive config files. Remember those IDE drives that would screw up if the jumper was in the wrong place? You'd get a similar error. I think it's similar, but with a file in the drive itself.

I know you really don't want to restore the MBR, but I believe that's your best bet. You don't need to make another live CD to get the boot-repair, just use your existing one and restore the MBR from there.

Here's the [page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) with instructions