# Latest ubuntu install: “Reloc offset is out of the segment”

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi

I am trying to install the latest release of ubuntu, that is 16.04, on a recent machine using UEFI. I am using a USB stick, which worked properly on another computer of mine (so I know the image was `dd`'ed properly).

After struggling a bit with secure boot and resorting to disabling it completely, I am now stuck with the following message when trying to boot the installation media:

```
reloc offset is out of the segment
Aborted. Press any key to exit.
```

Pressing a key returns to the bios' boot device selection.

Any idea? I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/327950/grub-rescue-toughies) that looks similar, but is unanswered.